# Shutdown multiple Windows XP machines with a Mac

Tags: macos, windows

I have a room full of Windows XP machines and I want to shutdown all the machines remotely with my Mac (10.8.2).

Can this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial to configure the windows machines: http://www.howtogeek.com/109655/how-to-remotely-shut-down-or-restart-windows-pcs/

Then install samba: http://forums.boxee.tv/showthread.php?t=38629

Then use the net command to execute the shutdown command just like from linux:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2330/shutdown-a-windows-machine-from-linux

If that works you can make a sh file with the command repeated for all the ip addresses of all the computers.

Comment: While the link you posted may answer the question, [it is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the contents of the link in your answer, then provide the link for reference. Links have a tendency disappear over time, leaving a non-applicable answer for those who may stumble upon your answer in the future.